# How to fix blender armature distorting my model?

Tags: animation, armature, transforms

This might be insanely easy or not possible, but does anyone know how to stop armatures from distorting certain axis' scales when I use rotate? For example, (which is why I'm making this) my player's arm looks more like a sea animal's fin instead of a classic arm when I rotate it. If you know how to make it keep the same scale and other properties but just be turned slightly I would really appreciate it. Thank you![image]

Comment: It looks like you've dcaled your armaure in Object mide, so first thing, apply the scale in Object mode

Comment: thank you so much @moonboots !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've scaled your armaure in *Object* mode, so apply the scale in *Object* mode.